# How do I loop through multiple child nodes of XML?

Tags: php, xml, loops

I am having some trouble trying to loop through an XML document. The XML looks like this:

```
<data>
<weather>
    <hourly>
        <time>0</time>
        <tempC>17</tempC>
        <tempF>62</tempF>
        <windspeedMiles>24</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>39</windspeedKmph>
    </hourly>
    <hourly>
        <time>3</time>
        <tempC>16</tempC>
        <tempF>60</tempF>
        <windspeedMiles>22</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>35</windspeedKmph>
    </hourly>
</weather>
<weather>
    <hourly>
        <time>0</time>
        <tempC>17</tempC>
        <tempF>62</tempF>
        <windspeedMiles>24</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>39</windspeedKmph>
    </hourly>
    <hourly>
        <time>3</time>
        <tempC>16</tempC>
        <tempF>60</tempF>
        <windspeedMiles>22</windspeedMiles>
        <windspeedKmph>35</windspeedKmph>
    </hourly>
</weather>
</data>
```

My code (below) whilst it loops through all 'weather' nodes, it only picks out the first 'hourly' child node and completely skips the second. Would someone be able to help me as if I am honest, I do not know enough about looping to fix it and its driving me nuts! Grr.

Here is my PHP code which loads an XML document from online and then formats the XML results into div tags and obviously loops through the XML but as I said only loops through the first 'hourly' node of each 'weather' node.

```
<?php
// load SimpleXML
$data = new SimpleXMLElement('myOnlineXMLdocument.xml', null, true);
echo <<<EOF
<div class="observationRow">
    <div class="observationTitleSmall"><br>Time</div>
    <div class="observationTitleSmall"><br>Temp C</div>
    <div class="observationTitleSmall"><br>Temp F</div>
    <div class="observationTitleSmall"><br>Wind Speed MPH</div>
    <div class="observationTitleSmall"><br>Wind Speed KMPH</div>
</div>
EOF;
foreach($data as $weather) // loop through our hours
{
echo <<<EOF
    <div>
        <div class="observationCellSmall"><br>{$weather->time}</div>
        <div class="observationCellSmall"><br>{$weather->tempC}</div>
        <div class="observationCellSmall"><br>{$weather->tempF}</div>
        <div class="observationCellSmall"><br>{$weather->hourly->windspeedMiles}</div>
        <div class="observationCellSmall"><br>{$weather->hourly->windspeedKmph}</div>
EOF;
}
echo    '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: OK, posted it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED CODE:

```
$str = "";
foreach($data->weather as $weather)
{
    foreach ($weather->hourly as $hour)
    {
        $str .= "
    <div>";

        if ($hour->time == "0") {
            $str .= "
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$weather->date</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$weather->maxtempC</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$weather->mintempC</div>";
        }

        $str .= "
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$hour->time</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$hour->tempC</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$hour->tempF</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$hour->windspeedMiles</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>$hour->windspeedKmph</div>
    </div>
    ";
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Using a slenderized version of your XML feed, that generates this:

```
   <div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>2013-08-19</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>17</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>15</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>0</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>15</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>59</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>11</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>18</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>300</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>15</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>59</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>13</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>21</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>2013-08-20</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>21</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>16</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>0</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>17</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>62</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>11</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>18</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>300</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>16</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>61</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>10</div>
        <div class='observationCellSmall'><br>17</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, this seems to be working perfectly! I knew I needed a loop within a loop but that was as close to a "solution" as I could come up with. However, this which you have posted seems to do the job so my many thanks. I am just going to throw the CSS together and then if you don't mind, I have one other question to ask but I will need to have the CSS coded first. Shall I mark this page as resolved or leave it open regarding the other question? Sorry, new here!

Comment: @Stephen If the other question is **very closely** related to the problem here, then post it here. I'll just answer again, and you can upvote me in both spots. :-) If the question is kind of different, then it should be a new question. The idea is we are creating an archive of sorts, and unique problems need to be searchable as unique problems.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'll run it by you quickly. So now that with your edits, all is working great. Although not in my code above, as well as having multiple hourly nodes with each weather node, I also have just 1 node for date (so it only gets listed once an not multiple times like the hourly node). IS there a way to list the date just once along with the multiple hourly entries. Im not sure if I am being clear but if you look at the link below, the weather is in tables but the date only gets listed once: [link](http://tinyurl.com/kgouav5)

Comment: @Stephen I'm sure there is. I'll need to see the XML to have a better idea. A link to the whole thing would be ideal, or you could patch together a simplified mock-up. -- It's getting late in my evening, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Here is a link to the XML I am actually using: http://tinyurl.com/lkp4sbr. Here is a link to what I have managed to achieve so far with your help: http://tinyurl.com/mnc4x47 but as you will see the date gets listed with every hour but the date only needs to be listed for each set of hours in a day. I am using tables in my example here but will switch to divs i think ultimately.

Comment: @Stephen. I think I know the path, but my day is done. I'll check back tomorrow. Meanwhile, if you want to play with it, I think the trick is to add a counter to the outer loop, and echo out the date and stuff if the counter is 0. That means busting up your heredoc a little, and those are the details I'm niggling over. But you're welcome to do so also. :-)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. If I am honest, I'm not sure I would be able to achieve this but any help youre willing to give s apprciated. Having said that, you have already helped a great deal so if you feel you canot do anymore, its no problem. I might be able to find someone on fiverr to pay to get the rest done but let me know. Again, my many thanks! :-)

Comment: @Stephen. Try this updated code. It outputs the right data where you need it. You'll need to play with CSS a little more to make things line up. If you prefer empty "cells", you can play around a bit more.

Comment: You.Are.A.Legend! What more can I say? A huge thank you! You do not know how many months it has taken me to try and write code to display these results but always failing. Thank you again Jeff :-) PS. I have 2 additional modifications. However, knowing when to stop asking is a good trait to have. However, as you seem to know what you are doing, would you be willing to modify further if I paid you? Is that even allowed to ask such a thing on here??

Comment: @Stephen. The only payment I take here are upvotes. Glad you're happy. Tell me what you need, and I'll see.

Comment: Well im more than happy to pay cold hard cash do dont be afraid to ask! The first thing is, within the PHP I need to know how to write str_replace for each of the nodes though an example just on one would be good. The 2nd thing is, would it be possible to switch from div tags to table elements, like in the orange example i showed you? I did just try using your edits on a table version of the PHP but it didnt work. Im undecided on whether i want to use divs or table cells.

Comment: I tried this in the table version and it didnt work: <td>{$hour->weatherCode}</td>.$weatherCode = str_replace('116', 'Cloud', $weatherCode);

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'll mail you over now.

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested loop. One to loop over the weathers, and and another to loop over the hourlies.

```
foreach($data->weather as $weather) {
   foreach($weather->hourly as $hourly) {
     // code here
   }
}
```

I don't remember the simplexml API 100% off my head, if that doesn't work you might need to use `->getChildren()` or something to make it iterable.

Either that, or use xpath and nab the hourlies directly: `/data/weather/hourly`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your speedy response. I think I have managed to get it working with Jeffs code but I appreciate your help too. All the best.

Comment: @Stephen: No problem, you're welcome. You should upvote the both of us and accept his answer if it solved your problem.